# How to store an image exists in resources directory in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

For example: 
I have the resources directory where I stored my HTML files there. So this is the sentence I put to print the image, but couldn't reach it.

image source:

> /resources/assets/images/Media/image.jpeg

So how to print the image if I'm now already in:

> resources/view/form/index.blade.php

I tried this one :

```
<img src="/resources/assets/images/Media/default.png">
```

but it's not working,

Thanks and appreciate any suggestions through the solution :)

Comment: Publicly available assets should be in the `public` folder. You can edit `webpack.mix.js` to copy your files from the `resources` folder over to the `public` folder and access them there.

Comment: You should tag the question with _one_ laravel version (if that is relevant to your question, that is). Anyway, the location of your blade file is irrelevant. The URL to the asset should be defined the document root. You probably have the document root pointed to the `public` folder (or at least, it should be), so if the image is in `public/assets/**/image.jpg`, then the URL would be `/assets/**/image.jpg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display the image on the website, store the image in the folder `public`, and it will be available. I.e.

`public/images/Media/default.png`

You can then use the `asset()`-function to generate the URL like:

```
$url = asset('images/Media/default.png');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Just a little note: The document root should be set to the `public`-folder, so `public` shouldn't appear in the URL. But otherwise correct :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Correct =), I just stated the whole path where to put the image for clarification. `asset()` won't include `public` in the generated URL.